# Codecademy Syntax Error unexpected token else

Tags: javascript, debugging

So I'm doing the JS codecademy course and I'm on the rock paper scissors thing, and I've seen other topics, but I don't have misplaced semicolons as far as I know. Can you tell me what's wrong?

```
var compare = function(choice1, choice2){

if(choice1 === choice2){
    return "The result is a tie!";
}else if(choice1 === "rock"){
    if(choice2 === "scissors"){
        return "rock wins";
    }else{
        return "paper wins";
}else if(choice1 === "paper"){
    if(choice2 === "rock"){
        return "paper wins";
    }else{
        return "scissors wins";
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: On a side note, sometimes Codecademy doesn't accept answers that are *correct*, but are not permitted as "acceptable" answers because of the rigid/specific syntax that is sometimes required. You should take a look at their Q/A section.

Comment: It's obviously something wrong with the curly braces.

Comment: i rolled it back because your edit, while indentig it "correctly" messed up the readability. the indention as is, is how it logically should be - there's just a `}` missing.

Comment: @VahidND Yeah, this code isn't correct, but sometimes Codecademy doesn't accept answers that are correct, but are not permitted as "acceptable" answers because of the rigid/specific syntax that is sometimes required.  If Andrew believed his code *was* correct, which he wasn't sure about, Codecademy's Q/A section would be a good resource for him in addition to S.O.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you messed up the braces:

```
var compare = function(choice1, choice2){
    if(choice1 === choice2){
        return "The result is a tie!";
    }else if(choice1 === "rock"){
        if(choice2 === "scissors"){
            return "rock wins";
        }else{
            return "paper wins";
        } // this was missing
    }else if(choice1 === "paper"){
        if(choice2 === "rock"){
            return "paper wins";
        }else{
            return "scissors wins";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you have an else followed by an else if:

```
else{
    return "paper wins";
}else if(choice1 === "paper"){
if(choice2 === "rock"){
    return "paper wins";
}
```

Comment: when you try to understand the intention behind the code, it's clear that a `}` is missing. otherwise, the resulting logic doesn't make sense.